# How to fill a TextArea with Values of DropDownList Using JavaScript in ASP

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

In a view, I have a DropDownList, a button and a TextArea.

How can I fill the panel with the values of DropDownlist when I click in the button.

I try to use javascript, but I think that's not working because when I click on the button, nothing happens.

This is the code :

```
<%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "dd" })%>
<input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="add"  onclick="addtext()"/>
<textarea ID="ta" cols="10" name="S1" rows="2" ></textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function addtext() {

            var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
            var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
            var add = document.getElementById('add');
            if (add.onkeypress) {
                ta.value = dd.selectedvalue;
            }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you missing `<` in text area tag ?

Comment: I do not see where you are calling the addtext() function. It will not be executed unless you call it.

Comment: thank you guys for answer,,,it s a mistake of copy paste ! see my update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your .net code is rendering a select list like the one below the problem is just in your javascript.  You need to use the selected index to get the option.  I was also unsure why you were checking if they keypress function existed on add.

```
<select id="dd"><option>a</option><option>b</option></select>
<input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="add"  onclick="addtext()"/>
<textarea ID="ta" cols="10" name="S1" rows="2" ></textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function addtext() {

            var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
            var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
            var add = document.getElementById('add');
            //if (add.onkeypress) {
                ta.value = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
            //}

        }
</script>
```

If you want to add the option from the select menu instead of replace then your function should look like this:

```
        function addtext() {

            var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
            var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
            var add = document.getElementById('add');
            //if (add.onkeypress) {
                ta.value = ta.value + dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
            //}

        }
```

If you only want the items in the textarea once I would store the selected values in an array and then replace the value with the joined values of the array.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var storedValues = [];
        function addtext() {

            var dd = document.getElementById('dd');
            var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
            var add = document.getElementById('add');
            //if (add.onkeypress) {
            var selectedValue = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
            if(storedValues.indexOf(selectedValue) === -1){
                storedValues.push(selectedValue)
                ta.value = storedValues.join('')
            }
            //}

        }
</script>
```

Comment: thx but I have to use DropDownList because I need it in other stuff !

Comment: That is fine.  It doesn't look like anything is wrong with your DropDownList, so these javascript changes should fix it.

Comment: thx topherd,,that's works !!! but still a problem,,,when i change another item and click in the button,,,the text in the textarea change also not be added (that s mean replaced)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood.  Are you trying to add the values to the textarea instead of replace them?  I added a function that concatenates the values instead of replaces them.

Comment: Nice !! it's works now,,,thanks alot,,,but please if you have time and you know it,,,can you please tell me how i delete repetition,,means one time the item must be added in the text area

Comment: I added a solution for only having the values appear once.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
ta.innerText = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].innerText;
```

Comment: should work. _textarea_ has property _innerText_, _select_ element has _options_ and _selectedIndex_, _option_ element has _innerText_. tried it on my own page.

Comment: thank you ,,,topherd find the solution,,but it still one problem take a look at the comments above please